# How to display the pager on top and bottom of a custom search results page?

Tags: 8, theming, search, paging

I have used the core Search Page functionality in Drupal 8 to built a search engine on my site.  The pager is displayed at the bottom by default. How can i display the pager on the top also?

**Note:** I have **not** used views to built the search page.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could use CSS

```
.[wrapping-div-class] { position: relative; }
.[wrapping-div-class] .pager { position: absolute; top: 0px; }
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But i need the pager BOTH on top and bottom. Any idea??

Answer (score 0):

You can add a custom page template for your search results page and then print the pager above the {{content}}

You can use the template name suggestions as listed here

[Twig template naming conventions - Drupal 8](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming/twig/twig-template-naming-conventions)

You can also use a preprocess function to duplicate the pager in the render array

[Preprocessing output in Drupal 8 - Acquia](https://docs.acquia.com/tutorials/fast-track-drupal-8-coding/pre-process-output-provided-other-modules/)